# Make the script wait for the generating Sparse file

Tags: php, linux, algorithm

I have a script that merges 2 files, and uploads it

1) Small file - LITERAL

2) LARGE FILE (where size<=2GB) - GENERATED

```
    # $file_size is <= 2GB

    # generate sparse
    $block_size = $file_size / 10;
    exec("dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse bs=" . $block_size . " count=0 seek=" . ($file_size - 32768),$tmp_array);

    sleep(12);

    # merge files
    exec("cat temp_file sparse > mergedFile");

    # remove temporary files
    exec("rm temp_file sparse");

    # upload the file now
```

My problem is, when it is merging the files, it takes a lot of time.

The merging process is skipped and the file is already uploaded, which should not be done until the whole Sparse file and the temporary file is Merged.

thanks for helping

~macki

Comment: you might also have a permission problem, are you sure the command is executing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec("cat temp_file sparse > mergedFile");` isn't waiting for the command to finish because you are redirecting the standard output of the cat command to a file. If you run a command like this in `exec()`, the command will run in the background and PHP will move immediately to the next line. Two possible solutions: either wrap the `cat temp_file sparse >mergedFile` inside of another shell script or do the file concatenation within PHP itself.

Comment: i will have to wait for the mergedFile to be completed, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look appending the sparse file onto the temp_file instead:

`exec("cat sparse >> temp_file");`

Update #1:

One thing that you are doing is generating a new file from two other files, effectively you are making a copy of each of them. To reduce the amount of disk activity, what you can do is append the `sparse` file onto the end of the `temp_file`. Then you can treat the `temp_file` the same as you would the `mergedFile` in you example. The other added benifit is that you will only need to delete the `sparse` file.

Here is a [simple tutorial](http://www.tlc-networks.polito.it/giaccone/corsi/laboratorio/Scripting/Bash/bash.html) on some of the basic bash commands you are likely to encounter.

Comment: @macki depending on how long the script takes to execute, you may want to consider setting your php timeout to a larger value, just so the script doesn't stop part way through. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use conditional operators? As a quick and dirty example:

`cat temp_file sparse > mergedFile && rm temp_file sparse`

Comment: that is not my problem, my problem is I wanted to know if the mergedFile is already completed, so that I could upload it immediately

Answer (score 0):

Instead to execute each program line one-by-one write a shell script and pass the variables block_size and seek as an argument. The command line parameters or the shell sciprt are referenced as $1, $2, etc. For example:

```
  exec("myscript " . $one . " " .$two);
```

And the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
```